# Diselected event for QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

I have a toolbar with lots of buttons. I want to disable some of them when there are no items selected in QTableWidget. I have no idea how to do that. Qt gives possibilities to detect which item is selected, but what about deselection? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to [selectionChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionChanged) or [itemSelectionChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) signal.

Comment: Ok, but this approuch enables to get changes in selection. But I need to catch event while diselecting